# How to change the Button size in a GridLayout to "match_parent"?

Tags: java, android, xml, grid-layout

I currently have this:

[image]

And I'm trying to get this:

[image]

I have tried for over an hour now, but cannot seem to get it working. Please take a look at my XML below.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/png1"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <GridLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <Button
            android:text="Button"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            android:layout_rowWeight="1"
            android:id="@+id/button1" />

        <Button
            android:text="Button"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            android:layout_rowWeight="1"
            android:id="@+id/button2" />

        <Button
            android:text="Button"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            android:layout_rowWeight="1"
            android:id="@+id/button3"
            android:layout_row="1"
            android:layout_column="1" />
        <Button
            android:text="Button"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            android:layout_rowWeight="1"
            android:id="@+id/button4"
            android:layout_row="1"
            android:layout_column="0" />
        <Button
            android:text="Button"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            android:layout_rowWeight="1"
            android:id="@+id/button5"
            android:layout_row="2"
            android:layout_column="0" />


    </GridLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

How can i change the last Button that he takes the whole place, like "match_parent"?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `android:layout_columnSpan="2"` to `android:id="@+id/button5"`. This will make the button span 2 columns.

```
   <Button
        android:text="Button"
        android:layout_columnSpan="2"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_columnWeight="1"
        android:layout_rowWeight="1"
        android:id="@+id/button5"
        android:layout_row="2"
        android:layout_column="0" />
```

Comment: I already tried to set android:layout_width="100dp" to android:layout_width="match_parent" but then this happens: https://i.gyazo.com/11594914718f3351ac8d35b58ab5c138.png

Comment: Please check my edited post. It should give you the result you want.

Answer (score 0):

please try to use this

```
android:layout_width="match_parent"
```

instead of `android:layout_width="100dp"`

Comment: I already tried to set android:layout_width="100dp" to android:layout_width="match_parent" but then this happens: https://i.gyazo.com/11594914718f3351ac8d35b58ab5c138.png